# What's the limit to how much someone can improve without hiring a chess coach?

Tags: learning, coach

I'm about 2000 on Lichess and I'm wondering how much farther I will be able to get without the help of a chess coach. I feel like you can only get so far with the help of a chess engine's analysis, which will tell you the best moves in each position but not describe any of the ideas or long-term plans.

Comment: It depends on the individual. Did Morphy have an engine or a coach? Did Capablanca?

Comment: lots of the historic players like capablanca and alekhine got pretty good. These days, with all the information accessible and advances in technology, it's much easier to get good without a coach. Of course, having a coach will often speed up the process, sometimes hugely.

Comment: Well, it depends on your age. Coach will do no good if you are an adult.

Comment: @SmallChess Interview after interview of adult improvers on the Perpetual Chess Podcast continue to provide anecdotal evidence that adult improvers benefit greatly from a coach. Do you have evidence to support your claim?